# not sure if i am doing right way the prevention of duplicate data on mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

Could anyone tell me the easiest and most useful way of how to prevent the duplicate data on MYSQL after the page is loaded and we try to refresh the page...

Actually I have an idea of using header() function to redirect to another file to the successful msg file right after the insertion part is done , but not sure if this is the right way of doing it....

I would like to hear someones else opinion about this case, as this is one of the things that an web developer must consider....

Comment: just check if the data exists in the table before inserting it?

Comment: Almost all questions I have seen, only asking opinions, has been closed. Provide some code, what you have tried, the real problem.

Comment: so first we have to check the db if we have already the data into it.... but wouldn't this be an extra operation, i mean it will increase the execution time ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [ON DUPLICATE KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) at the end of your query.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO `table`
(`column`)
VALUES
('thevalue')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `column` = `column`
```

The above just updates the existing record which prevents the insertion of duplicate records. Keep in mind you must have proper indexing to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use  header location  function  to redirect the  on  the same page  by this you can stop  duplicay

eg.  `<?php  header('location:http://google.com'); ?>`

Hope this will help you...